# Simulating plane seating with javascript array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to fill up the first class and and economy seats of a plane. However, when either first class or economy is full I would like there to be a pop up that would ask if you would like to sit in the other seating section if there are any seats left. If all the seats are full there should be a popup that says the plane is full.

I have the following js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Godin1/ba8Eu/

and the javascript:

```
var seatSection;
seatsAvailable = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];


check = function(){
seatSection = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value);

if (seatSection == 1) {
    firstClass();
} else if (seatSection == 2) {
    economy();
} else {
    other();
}
}

firstClass = function() {

for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    if (seatsAvailable[i] == 0) {
        window.alert("been assigned to first class seat " + i);
        seatsAvailable[i] = 1;
        break;
    }
};

}

economy = function() {

for (var i = 6; i <= 10; i++) {
    if (seatsAvailable[i] == 0) {
        window.alert("been assigned to economy seat " + i);
        seatsAvailable[i] = 1;
        break;

    }

};

}


other = function() {
window.alert("Wrong number");
}
```

Comment: So, what are you asking?

Comment: How to make it so that when the first class reaches 5 people it will ask if you would like to sit in economy if it has any seats available. Likewise if economy reaches its max of 5 people it should check to see if first class has any seats available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add a counter that counts how many seats have been taken:

```
var numberOfSeatsTaken = 0;
```

And then update the counter for each seat you reserve.
Here's an updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ba8Eu/4/) for your problem.

PS. if this is an assigment you really shouldn't ask for a solution to your problem - rather ask for help with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a boolean variable before your `for` loops called `seatFound` and set it to false.  Then in your loop, if you find a seat, you set it to true.  You then check after the `for` loop, and if its still false, then you know that there were no open seats, so you can check if the person wants to change sections.

`economy` then looks something like this:

```
economy = function() {
    var seatFound = false;
    for (var i = 6; i <= 10; i++) {
        if (seatsAvailable[i] == 0) {
            window.alert("been assigned to economy seat " + i);
            seatsAvailable[i] = 1;
            seatFound = true;
            break;
        }
    };
    if (!seatFound && window.confirm("There are no more economy class seats 
                       available. Would you like an first class seat?")) {
        first();
    }
}
```

Also, here is the updated version of your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ba8Eu/1/)

Comment: That works great for switching between if the plane is either full in first class or economy but what about if the plane is full in both seat sections? Is there a way to just have a popup that says both sections of the plane are full?

Comment: All you have to do for that would be to add a variable that keeps track of the total number of booked seats.  Then you just check whether or not its equal to the total number of seats.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/itsmikem/zYEf3/4/

```
var seatsAvailable = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var searchingElsewhere = false;

function checkAvailability() {
    var sectionRequested = parseInt(document.getElementById('seatNumber').value);
    switch (sectionRequested) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
            findSeat(sectionRequested);
            break;
        default:
            alert("Wrong number!");
    }
}

function findSeat(sectionRequested) {
    var searchRange = (sectionRequested == 1) ? {
        from: 0,
        to: 4,
        section: "first class"
    } : {
        from: 5,
        to: 9,
        section: "economy"
    };
    var foundNextAvailable = false;
    for (var i = searchRange.from; i <= searchRange.to; i++) {
        if (seatsAvailable[i] == 0) {
            alert(String("You're assigned to seat " + (i + 1) + " in " + searchRange.section + "."));
            seatsAvailable[i] = 1;
            foundNextAvailable = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (foundNextAvailable == false) {
        if (seatsAvailable.indexOf(0) == -1) {
            alert("Sorry, the plane is full.");
            return;
        } else {
            if (confirm("Section full.  Sit elsewhere in the plane?")) {
                if (searchingElsewhere == false) searchingElsewhere = true;
                var otherSection = (sectionRequested == 1) ? 2 : 1;
                findSeat(otherSection);
            }
        }
    }
}
```